# Decorators not working - TypeGraphql & TypeORM Netlify Functions

Tags: typescript, typeorm, netlify, typegraphql, netlify-function

I'm trying to run a typqgraphql server that uses typeorm library. Both libraries use decorators a lot.
When running `netlify dev` I get the following error:

```
{"errorMessage":"Column type for Country#code is not defined and cannot be guessed. Make sure you have turned on an \"emitDecoratorMetadata\": true option in tsconfig.json. Also make sure you have imported \"reflect-metadata\" on top of the main entry file in your application (before any entity imported).If you are using JavaScript instead of TypeScript you must explicitly provide a column type.","errorType":"ColumnTypeUndefinedError","stackTrace":["new ColumnTypeUndefinedError2 (/home/etudor/users-api/node_modules/src/error/ColumnTypeUndefinedError.ts:9:9)","/home/etudor/users-api/node_modules/typeorm/src/decorator/columns/Column.ts:143:23","__decorateClass (/home/etudor/users-api/.netlify/functions-serve/users-api-gql/src/users-api-gql.js:50:24)","Object.<anonymous> (/home/etudor/users-api/src/models/Country.entity.ts:21:3)","Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)","Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)","Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)","Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:828:14)","Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)","require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)"],"level":"error"}
```

OR this error

```
Error: Unable to infer GraphQL type from TypeScript reflection system. You need to provide explicit type for 'name' of 'Role' class.
  Object.findType (/home/etudor/users-api/node_modules/type-graphql/dist/helpers/findType.js:19:15)
```

I have tsconfig.json in my root directory and also tried moving it in the netlify/functions directory.

```
{
  "version": "2.4.2",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

Apparently netlify is not reading my tsconfig.json file or is not registering the decorators.

This is my netlify function

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
import { getApp } from '../../../src/server'
import ServerlessHttp from 'serverless-http'


const app = getApp()

exports.handler = ServerlessHttp(app)
```

Country entity

```
@Entity()
export class Country extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  uuid: string = generateUuid('ctr')

  @Column()
  name!: string

  @Column()
  code!: string
```

Role Entity

```
@ObjectType({ simpleResolvers: true })
@Entity()
export class Role extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryColumn()
  uuid!: string

  @Field()
  @Column()
  name!: string

  @Field({
    nullable: true,
  })
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  description?: string
```

Comment: Please share how you have defined `code` field in your `Country` entity

Comment: A simple test of whether tsconfig is being read or not will be to change `outDir` to some other location and then see if that change is reflected on build

Comment: @ranjan_purbey I did that and netlify didn't registered the change. So the file is not read when deploying or when running the lambda function

Comment: Do you get the same error when you deploy to cloud instead of running locally?

Comment: @ranjan_purbey yes, same error

Comment: @etudor did you ever get a working project out of this? It's a year later and I'm wondering if I should go serverless FaaS for GraphQL calls or just bite the bullet and pay for an EC2 instance to run an API

Answer (score 0):

I did the following configuration I created a constant sumulating the json the most important part is add the class entity name by importing (User, Client and User Client are entities with decorators)

```
export const connectionConfig: any = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: '#####',
  port: ###,
  username: '###',
  password: '####',
  database: '####',
  synchronize: true,
  logging: false,
  entities: [
    User,
    Client,
    UserClient       
  ],
  migrations: ['../migration/**/*.ts'],
  subscribers: ['../subscriber/**/*.ts'],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: '../entity',
    migrationsDir: '../migration',
    subscribersDir: '../subscriber'
  }
};
```

Finally you can create a class to intialize your typeorm. the function getConnection is going to be called by your service or repository level in your serverless project.

```
import { Connection, createConnection } from 'typeorm';
import { connectionConfig } from '../constants/typeorm';

// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export class TypeOrm {
  private static conn: Connection;

  static async getConnection() {
    if (!this.conn) {
      this.conn = await createConnection(connectionConfig);
    }
    return this.conn;
  }

  static async closeConnection() {
    if (this.conn) {
      console.log('Is been disconnected');
      await this.conn.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Call from service or repository layer

```
 static async getAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    const conn = await TypeOrm.getConnection();
    return conn.getRepository(User).find({ relations: ['userClients'] });
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried but get the same error. I think the issue is more from netlify not being able to read the tsconfig.json. If I run the code from `yarn start` then it compiles and runs